# How to trigger the list when user types list item from another intent in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have an List showing 3 items but when I select an item from the list(intent1) then it works and triggers the intent2 but after few intents if I again type the item name then the intent2 doesn't triggers and gives the response of fallback intent.

this is my code

```
const ItemList = {
    title: "Select to update.",
    items: {
      "Games": {
        title: "Games",
        description: "Click here to update Games details.",
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/2x/name.png',
          alt: 'p1',
        }),
      },
      "Books": {
        title: "Books",
        description: "Click here to update Books details.",
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/2x/name.png',
          alt: 'p2',
        }),
      },
      "Language": {
        title: "Language",
        description: "Click here to update Language details.",
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/2x/name.png',
          alt: 'p3',
        }),
      },
    },
  }


app.intent(SHOW_LIST_INTENT, (conv) => {
  conv.ask("Here's the list.");
  conv.ask(new List(ItemList));
});

app.intent(SELECTED_ITEM_INTENT, (conv, input, option) => {
    conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.AWAITING_ITEM, 1, {item: option});

    if (option === 'Games'){
      conv.ask(`Which is your favorite Game?`); 
    } else if (option === 'Language'){
      conv.ask(`Which ${option} do you know?`);
    } else if (option === 'Books'){
      conv.ask(`Your favorite ${option} name?`);
    }
});

app.intent(HANDLER_INTENT, (conv, parameters) => {
  const context = conv.contexts.get(AppContexts.AWAITING_ITEM);
  const selectedItem = context.parameters.item;


    if (selectedItem === 'Games'){
      conv.ask(`${parameters} is updated as your favorite Game. ` + `Your next preference?`);
      conv.ask(new Suggestions([`Add More Games`, `Show List`]));
    } else if (selectedItem === 'Books'){
      conv.ask(`${parameters} is updated as your favorite Book. ` + `Your next preference?`);
      conv.ask(new Suggestions([`Add More Books`, `Show List`]));
    } else if (selectedItem === 'Language'){
      conv.ask(`${parameters} is updated as your Language. ` + `Your next preference?`);
      conv.ask(new Suggestions([`Add More Language`, `Show List`]));
    }
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I want to trigger the SELECTED_ITEM_INTENT when user says Add More Games

how to get this, is there anything missing in the code.

[image: ShowListIntent]
[image: SelectedItemIntent]
[image: HandlerIntent]

Comment: It is a little difficult to tell, since you haven't included how the intents mapped to HANDLER_INTENT, SELECTED_ITEM_INTENT, and SHOW_LIST_INTENT are expected to handle user input. If you can update your question to show the screen shots from these Intents in the Dialogflow UI, we may better be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Prisoner I have updated the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I think the design of your conversation is a little confused, and this may be making it more difficult to do exactly what you want.

Your `SELECTED_ITEM_INTENT` is only triggered based on interaction with the list, and you are prompting them to say something. Since the list is no longer active, and you don't have any Intents set to handle any of the phrases, then nothing will match.

Rather than relying on a visual list (which will not work well for all Assistant platforms), you may want to approach it more as a voice conversation. Under this model, you can picture conversations that look something like this:

```
Agent: Would you like to update the Games, Books, or Language details?
User:  Games
Agent: What is your favorite game?
User:  Rock, paper, scissors
Agent: Rock, paper, scissors has been set as your favorite game. What would you like to update next?
User:  Another game
...
```

Or the conversation could go something like this

```
Agent: Would you like to update the Games, Books, or Language details?
User:  Game details
Agent: What is your favorite game?
User:  Rock, paper, scissors
Agent: Rock, paper, scissors has been set as your favorite game. What would you like to update next?
User:  Another game
...
```

But what if they said something like this instead?

```
Agent: Would you like to update the Games, Books, or Language details?
User:  Books
Agent: What is your favorite book?
User:  I meant game
Agent: What is your favorite game?
User:  Rock, paper, scissors
Agent: Rock, paper, scissors has been set as your favorite game. What would you like to update next?
User:  I don't know
...
```

From this, we might think that users would reply in one of three ways:

1. Indicating what category they want with phrases such as "Book", "Games", "Language details", "I mean games", "Add more languages", "Another book", etc.

   - This suggests that each category might be a good Entity for the phrases the user might say.
2. With the value of whatever they're updating

   - This is well handled by using a Context to know when we're asking for something specific. As you've done.
3. Asking for help with phrases such as "What can I do?" or "I don't understand."

Each of these would be done using an Intent with phrases and Input Contexts tuned for those phrases. In the output, we might use Suggestion Chips where appropriate to cue for the possible categories we expect for the first Intent.

But we haven't considered a few other things the user might have said. What, for example, if we had

```
Agent: Rock, paper, scissors has been set as your favorite game. What would you like to update next?
User:  Add another one
```

The user knows that they just set a game, and they want to set another one. But they haven't used the term "game" specifically. We will need to keep track of what category they last updated in a Context and have another Intent that can handle phrases like "Add another one" or "The same thing".

But what if our users start doing this a lot and we have an interaction such as

```
Agent: Rock, paper, scissors has been set as your favorite game. What would you like to update next?
User:  Add a book named Dungeon Masters Guide
```

Here, they've combined to things that we thought of as separate Intents. So we may need to add an Intent that handles phrases such as this, where they specify both the category and the information at the same time.